# Multiple upload inputs using ng2-uploader in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, file-upload

I'm using https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng2-uploader package for file upload in angular, everything works fine for single input. But I want more than one input with different options and urls like this

```
<input type="file"
   ngFileSelect
   [options]="options1"
   (onUpload)="handleUpload($event)"
   (beforeUpload)="beforeUpload($event)">

<input type="file"
   ngFileSelect
   [options]="options2"
   (onUpload)="handleUpload($event)"
   (beforeUpload)="beforeUpload($event)">
```

Configuration for file upload I'm trying to do is

```
this.options1 = {
            url: 'url for first input' 
            fieldName: 'first input field name',
            method: 'PUT'
        };

this.options2 = {
            url: 'url for second input' 
            fieldName: 'second input field name',
            method: 'PUT'
        };

    handleUpload(data): void {
     if (data && data.response) {
     data = JSON.parse(data.response);
     this.uploadFile = data;
     //code
     }
    }

 fileOverBase(e:any):void {
  this.hasBaseDropZoneOver = e;
 }

 beforeUpload(uploadingFile): void {
  if (uploadingFile.size > this.sizeLimit) {
  uploadingFile.setAbort();
  alert('File is too large');
  }
 }
```

This results in always picking up the latter options i.e 'options2' and 'options1' donot have any effect. How do I implement this?

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue.
And in my case, I had duplicates of input's `ids` and label's `for` picked the wrong one.

By the way **ng2-uploader** was renamed to **ngx-uploader**. Recently its api changed a lot, but there was versions compatible with **ng2-uploader**, with some bugs fixed.